# Sharepoint 2010 grouping workflow tasks for a document library

Tags: 2010, workflow, document-library, tasks, task-list

We want SharePoint Experts Advice here

**What we have :**

1- we have one document library ( many items).

2- we have many Tasks assign to document library item by workflow e.g. Require Manager Approval, Require Manager Review e.t.c

**What we want :**

Grouping Document library on basis of Task for e.g. Manager view document library items with tabs such as Require Manager Approval and Require Manager Review and on clicking Document Library items in a certain Tab we have associated action to perform e.g. Approve, Reject e.t.c

**Question :**

We know we can display task list it self but we want document library which is grouped on basis of Task ( Tabs), any one guide me how to accomplish this..Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to let the workflow set a Status column based on the state and then create views based on that Status column (could just be one view grouped on the column)

Comment: That's the best approach and do it for all my workflows so users have an idea where exactly the item sits in the workflow process.  Simply In Progress and Complete are not enough of an indicator.

Comment: perfect ...that what i was looking for ...thanks allot